# On supremum of a function which is defined in terms of an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Let $s>0$, $a=\ln(1+tan(\pi/8))$, and we define $$f(s)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{2\pi e^{a+s\pi \cos \theta}}{2+2e^{a+s\pi \cos \theta}\cos(\pi \sin \theta)+e^{2a+2s\pi \cos \theta}} \sqrt{s^2\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}\, d\theta..$$

I used wolfram alpha to test different values of $f(s)$ by inputting different numbers $s$. It seems that $f(s) \ge 3\pi/2$, and as $s \rightarrow \infty$, $f(s) \rightarrow 3\pi/2$.

My question is that, can we rigorously show that $f(s) \ge 3\pi/2$ for all $s>0$? Or can anyone give me some advice on how to numerically plot the graph of the function $f(s)$? I don't have any background in numerical methods.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have a look at my edit. We can have a better looking formula for $f(s)$ even if it does not help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where you have been able to catch *this monster* but, from a numerical point of view, you are totally correct.

$$f(s)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \color{blue}{\text{monster}(\theta)} \, d\theta$$ 
$$f(0)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{ \pi  \cos (t)}{ \cos (\pi  \sin (t))+\sqrt{2}} \, d\theta$$ 
$$\int \frac{ \pi  \cos (t)}{ \cos (\pi  \sin (t))+\sqrt{2}} \, d\theta=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2}   \sin
   (t)\right)\right)$$ gives $f(0)=2 \pi$.

Excluding this case, numerical integration gives
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
s & f(s) -\frac{3\pi}2 \\
 1 & 0.24678885072343 \\
 2 & 0.02299334512947 \\
 3 & 0.00414710593807 \\
 4 & 0.00122295840181 \\
 5 & 0.00048378201857 \\
 6 & 0.00022918421614 \\
 7 & 0.00012245793655 \\
 8 & 0.00007132786660 \\
 9 & 0.00004434040661 \\
 10 & 0.00002900456473 \\
 20 & 0.00000179588347 \\
 30 &  0.00000035414006 \\
 40 &  0.00000011198578
\end{array}
\right)$$
 I *suppose* that the limit is correct. How to prove it ? That is the question.

What is interesting to notice is that $f(s)$ goes through a maximum value of $6.31145$ for $s=0.09125$.

**Edit**

Using $t=\cos ^{-1}(u)$, the problem reduces to
$$f(s)=2 \pi\int_0^1 \frac {\sqrt{s^2-\left(s^2-1\right) u^2} } { \sqrt{1-u^2} \left(\sqrt{2} \cosh (\pi  s u)+\cos \left(\pi 
   \sqrt{1-u^2}\right)\right)}\, du$$ which is slightly more pleasant even if it does not help at all.

Comment: Thanks your very much for your attention and post for this problem. It actually comes from the question of computing the length of right half of the family of ellpises: $\frac{(x-a)^2}{s^2}+y^2=\pi^2$  connecting the two points $(a,\pm \pi)$ under the conformal metric $g=e^{2u}\delta$, where $\delta$ is the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u(x,y)=\ln\left(\frac{2e^x}{2+2e^x\cos y+e^{2x}}\right)$.

Comment: Could you show me how to numerically plot the function $f(s)$? I don't have any numerical analysis background. I'm wondering what software did you use to get the table and find the maximum?

Comment: @student. Brrrrr ! You are very welcome ! Interesting problem, for sure. I am still working it (very little hope, but who knows ?). Cheers :-)

Comment: @student. As you did, generating a table of result. Why don't you register at Wolfram Cloud ? It is free and you have all Mathemetica to play with.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your time! I will register the wolfram cloud. It is an interesting problem but hard to solve from a mathematical point of view. I hope someday I can find a simple proof from a geometric point of view...